# $\pi(C_0(X))$ is a quasi diagonal set of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a second countable locally compact Hausdorff space, let $C_0(X)$ be the $C^*$algebra of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Definition: $C_0(X)$ is called quasi diagonal, if $C_0(X)$ admits a faithful *-representation $\pi:C_0(X)\to B(H)$ and an increasing sequence $(p_n)_n$ of finite rank  of projections on $H$ that converges strongly to $id_H$ and such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|p_n\pi(a)-\pi(a)p_n\|=0.$$

The task is to prove that for $C_0(X)$.

Consider $\pi=\bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}ev_x:C_0(X)\to \bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$ given by $\pi(f)=\sum\limits_{x\in D}f(x)$, ($ev_x$ denotes the evaluation at $x$) where $D$ is a countable dense subset of $X$.

Next step  is to construct a sequence of finite rank projections $(p_n)\subset \pi(C_0(X))$ with the following properties:

(i) $p_n\le p_{n+1}$ for all $n$, (ii) $\|ap_n-p_na\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ for all $a\in \pi(C_0(X))$ and (iii) $\|p_n(x)-x\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ for all $x\in \bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$.

My plan is to construct the sequence in the following way: choose $p_1$ as the projection on $\bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$ onto the first coordinate of $\bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$, $p_2$ as the projection on $\bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$ onto the first two coordinates of $\bigoplus\limits_{x\in D}\mathbb{C}$ and so on. To check that $(p_n)\subset \pi(C_0(X))$, it probably works with Urysohn's lemma.

Question: Does this construction of $(p_n)$ work, or do I fail to notice something? If it's wrong, which sequence is a correct one? Or, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not true that $p_n\in \pi(C_0(X))$ (it may work for carefully chosen $X$, but not in general).

Other than that, your construction works. In fact, $\pi(a)p_n-p_n\pi(a)=0$ for all $n$ and all $a$.